# How do I tell Tabbarview to include the remaining height at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socialuni_deneme/colors.dart';
import 'package:socialuni_deneme/pages/log_in_page.dart';

class Deneme extends StatefulWidget {
  const Deneme({super.key});

  @override
  State<Deneme> createState() => _DenemeState();
}

class _DenemeState extends State<Deneme> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabController _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: screenSize.width,
          height: screenSize.height,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: screenSize.height * 0.15,
                width: screenSize.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/social_uni_logo.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                labelColor: AppColors.lacivert,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Giriş Yap",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Kayıt Ol",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: screenSize.width,
                height: screenSize.height,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top:
                        20), // Email Text'inin Tab Barın az aşağısına inmesi için
                child: Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              LogInPage(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text("Kayit Ol"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socialuni_deneme/colors.dart';
import 'package:socialuni_deneme/styles.dart';

class LogInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LogInPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
          child: Text(
            "Email",
            style: ralewayStyle.copyWith(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 6,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            style: ralewayStyle.copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              prefixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.email,
                  color: AppColors.lacivert,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18),
              hintText: "Okul Emailiniz",
              hintStyle: ralewayStyle.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                  fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
          child: Text(
            "Şifre",
            style: ralewayStyle.copyWith(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 6,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            style: ralewayStyle.copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              prefixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.lock,
                  color: AppColors.lacivert,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18),
              hintText: "Şifreniz",
              hintStyle: ralewayStyle.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                  fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 32,
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("Giriş Yapıldı");
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: AppColors.buttonColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Giriş Yap",
                    style: ralewayStyle.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18)),
              ), // BoxDecoration
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Gw6.png)

I get an error like this, how can I simply tell tabbarview to get the remaining height of the screen?

I need to tell tabbarview to cover the remaining height, I tried to wrap it with many things and at that time I encountered different different other problems and I could not get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have added unnecessary widgets as parent and as well as child to `TabBarView`.

Here is a minimalistic approach for the build method that serves the purpose.
NOTE: I have made some variable constant to check how it renders. Please replace those with your original

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabController _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: screenSize.width,
          height: screenSize.height,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: screenSize.height * 0.15,
                width: screenSize.width,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/social_uni_logo.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Giriş Yap",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Kayıt Ol",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green.shade100,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      children: const [
                        LogInPage(),
                        Text("Kayit Ol"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is const solving the problem or putting the extended widget on top of the container, where exactly did I go wrong? By the way thank you so much <3

Comment: Not the const, its best practice to have the const. The issue was with the nested column inside the TabBarView. TabBarView children's are the individual pages that you wish to navigate to while swiping or tapping the Tabs.

Comment: please mark this a helpful if the solution has helped you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. 

I can't :) I'am new here and ı dont have 15 points :(